# Car Mode suddenly appeared - why? And how do I get rid of it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-evo

About 2 1/2 hrs ago, I plugged in my HTC Evo 4G to its home charger to charge up a bit before leaving the house. It's rooted running CyanogenMod-7.1.0-Supersonic (for at least a month if not more, I can't remember when my husband did this).

Within about 3 minutes, my phone had this really weird user interface I have never seen. It's Car Mode. I couldn't exit out of it, couldn't make my phone respond to me at all. I immediately pulled out the battery & rebooted, thinking maybe it was malware. It booted back into Car Mode, only this time I could click an Exit button.

Researching, I see that this is an UI for car docking. Only I have no car dock, and it was plugged into my home wall charger. I left the house for errands, and no matter what I did - on the phone on a voice call, typing email (at a doctor's office, not driving ;) ), and it kept booting me into Car Mode. On the voice call it automatically put me on speaker.

I did not ask for this program, did not download anything, did not approve anything...

I ran Lookout and no Malware or Spyware is showing. I am very confused.

Anyone have ideas on what this program is, how it all of a sudden appeared on my phone, and how to get it off? I looked up apps in Google Play and the icon in the notifications bar (when I exit Car Mode) is not something that is there. It looks like an app, but it's not in my Apps manager, either, or a running process that I can tell, yet it is showing up intermittently in my notifications, even not plugged in or moving. It's also turning on intermittently. I can't get anything done.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: car mode is supposed to show up automatically when the device is put into a car dock; the mode is triggered by a set of magnets arranged in a certain pattern. Check if you have any magnets around that might trigger the mode.

Answer (score 10):

It is included with Cyanogenmod and is based on similar modes in other ROMs. It is meant to provide you with what you need, but not so much as to distract you while driving.

I do not know what is launching it, or how it is doing so automatically, but there may be ways to stop it:

### Stop it in it's tracks

If you would like to remove it completely and not use it at all, install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en), choose the `Backup and Restore` tab, find and select `Car Home` (I have version 2.2.1.2) and select either `Freeze` or `Uninstall`.

**Note:** `Freeze` will stop the app from running at all, but keep it on your phone. `Uninstall` will completely remove it.

**Double note**: if you choose `Uninstall`, you may want to make a `Backup` there with the app first, just in case removing it causes unwanted side-effects.

---

### Other, less intense options

1. In car mode, click the `Right Arrow` and choose `Settings`. From here, make sure that it's not automatically launching when connected to some bluetooth device, and try `Reset to defaults`, just to make sure nothing else is helping it along.
2. From the home screen, go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications`, choose the `All` tab, and find `Car Home`. Here, click the `Clear data` button.

Answer (score 5):

The most common reason for the car mode to launch is dirt in your charger-connector. The micro-USB gathers all kinds of dirt from your pockets and eventually starts connecting the pins sporadically.

Apply some compressed air and you will be fine. Let the charger have some as well.

Answer (score 4):

I found another Car Home issue related to the USB port.  On a non-EVO someone dicovered that their USB port was bent and they violently disabled it.

Since Iplugged and unplugged my EVO 3.1415 million times since I got it, I've played around (gently) with the USB port.

This has reduced the annoying Car Home app starts from all the time to 4-5 times daily.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable car mode in your phone model by going to `Settings > Dock > and uncheck auto-launch`, according to http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110814065550AAW9RZc

Apparently this is a common problem in EVO 4G, see:

- http://forums.miui.us/showthread.php?21516-Car-Mode-won-t-turn-off
- http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-all-things-root/343337-car-mode-constantly-randomly-turns.html

Answer (score 3):

It was a hardware issue for me - need to gently bend the charging port so it doesn't touch the upper bracket. More info here:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-droid-charge/135723-fixed-droid-charge-stuck-desk-car-cradle-mode.html

It's happened to me several times: randomly switches to car mode, desktop mode, shuts off speaker, answers calls only in speakerphone, music won't play through speaker, etc..

Answer (score 1):

How to get out of car mode.

Got this from http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/203433-how-get-out-car-mode.html after trying all of the above and nothing had worked.  This worked for me.

I see that there are only a few posts about this online but no solutions without using apps. I called Verizon and told them the issues. They actually had to go back to way earlier models to solve this issue. To get out of car dock mode do the following:

- Plug in your phone to your charger.
- Turn off your phone.
- Turn on your phone.
- Place a call. While in call, remove your charging cable from your phone (wiggling it a little did the trick for me).
- End the call.

The steering wheel icon should be gone and your phone should be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was having this problem with my LG G2 and finally figured out how to get rid of it. Hoping this saves someone else the frustration!

Go into Settings and under the System heading there is an option for Accessory. When you open that, uncheck the "car Home" option that says "automatically start car home when the phone is mounted on car cradle".

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you disable the Kies Air program then the care mode will stop working on the Galaxy S2.

Click on settings, then find applications, under running process there is a program called "Kies air" (orange and white in color.) click on the un install updates and then I clicked on disable button.

I have a Samsung galaxy 2 and the "car mode" has stopped popping up every 2 seconds on my phone

Comment: Please add more details to clarify your answer

Comment: Sorry,  click on settings,  then find applications,   under running process there is a program called "Kies air"   (orange and white in color.)  click on the un install updates and then I clicked on disable button.   I have a Samsung galaxy 2 and the "car mode"  has not been popping up every 2 seconds on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I jus figured all you had to do was use two of your fingers and swipe them down twice.   (-_-). That car mode got me worried!!!  I though I was never gonna get out of it!!!

Comment: Why too many exclamation marks?

Comment: Too much coffee!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with my HTC One M7 (root, OmniROM) that the car mode appeared after restart although no usb cable/dock was connected.

I had anomalities like screen rotation (although locked), calls starting in speaker-mode, mtp-usb not working (disconnect after 1s).

Tapping "Exit Car Mode" didn't solve the problem. Possibly the "car mode" was not terminated fully. Nothing I read on the forums helped **until I  found the solution:**

The App [Car Mode *root*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.warner.carmode) was able to terminate the car mode task so that I could use my phone normally again.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to fix my Droid DNA by going into Developer Options and checking "USB debugging"